# Como fazer para deslizar entre páginas na horizontal usando um menu fixo?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Esse é meu código Html, e também estou usando CSS com `position: fixed;` no menu.

Código:

```
<body>
    <div class="topo">
        <img src="img/logo.png" />
        <div class="menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Quem Somos</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Localização</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Cardápio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Promoções</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Fale Conosco</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="corpo">
        conteudo
    </div>
```

Comment: de uma olhada neste demonstrativo https://codyhouse.co/demo/horizontal-timeline/index.html fiz um site com este esquema e fica muito legal aqui tem outros exemplos de scripts bem, bonitos
https://www.sitepoint.com/10-jquery-horizontal-scroll-demos-plugins/

Answer (score 1):

vc pode utilizar algo como:

```
$(function(){
  $('.menu').find('a').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.corpo').scrollLeft( $(this).data('scroll') );
    })
});
```

mas pra que isso funcione vc precisa adicionar a propriedade data-scroll nos links do menu passando um valor dentro.

veja aqui:
http://codepen.io/pen/xRbrNo

Answer (score 0):

Se eu entendi direito, você quer que o conteúdo da página deslize pro lado, escondendo o conteúdo enquanto a nova página aparece deslizando pelo lado oposto, certo?

Por Exemplo: Clico em "Quem Somos", a página "Home" desliza pro lado esquerdo e some, a página "Quem Somos" desliza pelo lado direito e aparece, certo?

Se for isso, vamos lá:

**Nota**: Fiz o código meio que na pressa, você vai ter que arrumar direitinho, é possível otimizar o código, ai é contigo.

Você pode ver a demo [clicando aqui](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BQywRE) (aproveitei o pen do @user2084932).

## CSS

```
.corpo{
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.content {
  animation-duration: .4s;
}

p {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 2px solid #666;
}

.slideLeft {
  animation-name: kf_SlideLeft;
}

.slideFromRight {
  animation-name: kf_SlideFromRight;
}

@keyframes kf_SlideLeft {
  from {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }

  to {
    transform: translateX(-2048px);
  }
}

@keyframes kf_SlideFromRight {
  from {
    transform: translateX(2048px);
  }

  to {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
```

## Javascript

```
$(function(){
  // A gente pega o delay no css. Se quisermos alterar a duração,
  // mudamos apenas no css.
  var delay = parseFloat($(".content").css("animation-duration").replace("s"));

  $("[href='#home']").click(function(e) {    
    $(".content").addClass("slideLeft");

    // Só devemos alterar o conteúdo APÓS a animação terminar, fazemos
    // isso multiplicando o delay por 1000.
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      $(".content").removeClass("slideLeft").addClass("slideFromRight");
      $(".content").html("<p>Home Content</p>");

      window.setTimeout(function() {
        $(".content").removeClass("slideFromRight");
      }, delay * 1000);
    }, delay * 1000);

    e.preventDefault();
  });

  $("[href='#quem']").click(function(e) {
    $(".content").addClass("slideLeft");

    // Vai executar assim que a animação terminar.
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      $(".content").removeClass("slideLeft").addClass("slideFromRight");
      $(".content").html("<p>Quem Somos - Content</p>");

      // Segundo timeout pra remover a classe.
      window.setTimeout(function() {
        $(".content").removeClass("slideFromRight");
      }, delay * 1000);
    }, delay * 1000);

    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Acho que o código dispensa muitas explicações, porque ele é bem simples e meio que auto explicativo.

Basicamente, o que faz o conteúdo deslizar é o `transform: translateX`. Valores negativos e ele irá mover para a esquerda, valores positivos para a direita.

O que faz o ato de deslizar ficar "smooth", é a animação. Se você colocar só o `transform`, você não vai ver o conteúdo deslizando, ele vai simplesmente sumir.

Outra maneira de deixar suave, seria usar `transition`, porém, a animação `slideFromRight` teria de ser feita de outra forma, porque `transition` é apenas a forma que seria feita a transição de algumas propriedades, enquanto que a animação eu consigo controlar os valores iniciais e finais com `from` e `to`.

#### Referências:

[CSS Animations](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp)
[CSS Transitions](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp)
[CSS Transforms](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_2dtransforms.asp)